# EJBGen on JDK 1.8

Tags: java-8

I am trying to run EJBGen for generating EJB DDs and the interfaces.
The application was targeted to Weblogic 8.1 on JDK 1.4.

Recently we are trying to migrate it to Weblogic 12.1.3 on JDK 1.8.
But as I am trying to run EJBGen, its saying that EJBGen isn't supported by JDK version higher than 1.7.

Any suggestion on how I can migrate the EJBs to Weblogic 12.1.3 on JDK 1.8 with **minimum changes**?

Comment: Why not just upgrade to new ejb spec? Its simpler and more maintainable. I went through the same process for a client and the re-factoring straight forward, unless you need to support older specs for some reason.

Comment: Can you please provide references of some good tutorials/documents on how to refactor older EJB to the latest spec? We need a process which will have minimum code changes.

Comment: This is not really possible without analysing the extent to which you use EJB's in your code base. If you use intellij you can just apply the ejb 3.0 style by right clicking on a project and selecting apply the style. Does most of the hard work for you.

Comment: It is fixed now. please ref http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES388